# Display error when argument is specified multiple times

Tags: python, argparse

When specifying the same argument multiple times, the default argparse behaviour is that the last specified value "wins", overwriting  the previous value. I want argparse to show an error when the same argument is specified multiple times instead of silently overwriting the first specified value.

How can that be done?

My current code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '-t', '--test',      # either of this switches
    type=str,            # parameter is string
    dest='test',         # store in 'test'.
    required=True        # required
)
```

Calling the script:

```
myscript.py -t hello -t world
```

leads to no errors, `test` has the value *world*. I want argparse to show an error in this case, as the default behaviour is error prone from my point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest option is to use `action="append"` and check if the result has len > 1:

```
parser.add_argument(
    '-t', '--test',
    type=str,
    dest='test',
    action='append',
    required=True
)

args = parser.parse_args()

if len(args.test) > 1:
   ...error
```

But a nicer way would be to solve the problem within the parser, so that you get unified error handling. This can be done with a custom Action like this:

```
class Once(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if hasattr(self, 'seen'):
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, 'only one please')
        setattr(self, 'seen', True)
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '-t', '--test',
    type=str,
    dest='test',
    action=Once,
    required=True
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Previously didn't find the duplicates, but after comparing duplicates and this one, I like this one more, the error by argpase.ArgumentError looks nicer to me.

Comment: Thanks, but see my update. `if getattr(namespace...` has problems with default arguments, an explicit flag appears to be cleaner.